# Help finding references on WKB approxiamtion of gravitational waves in a curved background

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, resource-recommendations, gravitational-waves, semiclassical

In MTW Gravitation, the shortwave approximation on gravitational waves in a curved background is given in Section 35.13. This treatment is similar to the WKB approximation in quantum mechanics, or the geometric optics in electromagnetism.  The authors pointed to two more rigorous treatment.

One of them is Y. Choquet -Bruhat's work  Commun. Math. Phys. 12, 16 (1969). Unfortunately, I only read Chinese and English. Is there any translated version?

The second reference is referred as "MacCallum and Taub (1973)", but the author did not actually any information on this reference in the Bibliography. Do you know what it is?

Comment: Did you check the Comm Math Phys article? They are usually in English, I've read her plenty in English. You have to check for journal, Taub was a well known mathematician (the good kind) in GR.

Comment: @BobBee I did check Choquet-Bruhat's article. It is not in English. Let me see if I can find Taub's works.

Comment: Could have also been J Math Phys, he published some there.

Comment: @BobBee I got Taub's article. It is http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01645977.

Comment: I looked at the first page, he says he reviews Choquet Bruhat method also, so it might give you most of what you need. I took a GR course with him, he and Sachs also at Berkeley worked together, I did my thesis with Sachs. I must have know McCallum but can't remember.

Comment: @BobBee Thanks! I read MacCallum and Taub's work, but I find it difficult to accept their particular way of doing the variational principle. It seems to me that their procedure of doing variational principle is just to obtain the equations Isaacson already did in some kind of formal way. This is the only point of their variational principle.